# SQL insert date into database

Tags: java, sql, database, insert

I use `java.util.Date` to get the date and I get the date format like this

> Sat Jun 29 11:07:25 CDT 2013

When I try to insert it into the database using

```
String QueryString = "INSERT INTO db (day) Values ('"+d+"');";
    st.executeUpdate(QueryString);
```

I get this

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string."

How can I insert that type of date into the db?

Should I declare it as a string?

Comment: parameterized the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can i insert that type of date into the db? should i declare it as a string?

No - you should avoid even the string conversion you *currently* have. You shouldn't build your SQL dynamically like that - it's a recipe for SQL injection attacks, hard-to-read code, and conversion failures.

Instead, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and set the parameter using [`setDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29):

```
// TODO: Closing the statement cleanly in a finally block or try-with-resources
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO db (day) Values (?)");
pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(d.getTime()));
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Note that `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, but they're somewhat different. It's never been clear to me which time zone is used to convert the given instant in time into a real date - and the documentation is less than helpful. It's broken by design in my view, but that's a different matter. You can use another `setDate` overload which accepts a `Calendar` - which is used for the time zone. It's still all horribly unclear, but hopefully you can get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) to be compatible with the databse

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use an [updatable ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html):

```
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement("select day from db", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
rs.moveToInsertRow();
rs.updateDate(1, yourJavaSqlDateObject);
rs.insertRow();
rs.first();
```

Though, depending on your driver/database, there may be a write-lock on the table.

Date formatting should be done on output, not input. Let the database decide how best to store the date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your Date object

```
Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); //Your date

String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(d);

String QueryString = "INSERT INTO db (day) Values ('"+dateString+"');";
st.executeUpdate(QueryString);
```